# integer showing as NaN

Tags: jquery

I'll begin with posting my javascript.

```
    $(document).on('click','.remove-single-inbox-message', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var messageid = $(this).data('messageid');
    var messages = $("#number-messages").html();
    var messages = parseInt(messages, 10);
    messages--;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '?a=profile_message_delete',
        data: {
            "messageid" : messageid
        },
        success: function(){
            $('.table-row'+messageid).hide();
            if(messages == 0){
                $("#insert-message-indicator").html("");
            } else {
                $("#insert-message-indicator").html("<strong><small>"+messages+"</small></strong>&nbsp;<i class='icon-envelope icon-white' rel='tooltip' title='New messages available'></i>");
        }
        }
    });
});
```

The first decrementation works fine and the new number is displayed but the ones that follows it shows NaN. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should avoid declaring the same variable (messages) twice.

Comment: Any short explanation why? Just curious.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Possibility 1 :**

You mixed the id while posting and `"#number-messages"` should be `"#insert-message-indicator"`.

Replace

```
var messages = $("#number-messages").html();
```

with

```
var messages = $("#number-messages").text();
```

The `"<strong><small>"` you add makes the html unparsable as an integer.

**Possibility 2 :**

When doing `$("#insert-message-indicator").html("<...` you're erasing the element with id `#number-messages` and so `$("#number-messages").html()` returns nothing usable at second iteration.

**Warning :**

```
var messages = $("#number-messages").html();
var messages = parseInt(messages, 10);
```

is the same than

```
var messages = $("#number-messages").html();
messages = parseInt(messages, 10);
```

You should probably have something like

```
var messages_text = $("#number-messages").html();
var messages = parseInt(messages_text, 10);
```

because your current code is confusing.

Comment: okay another thing I just noticed is that I forgot to put the id selector in the relevant element @ callback function so there is no element to collect value from after first click.

Comment: I did: var messages = parseInt($("#number-messages").text(), 10); worked like a charm :) thanks for the help!